# Angularjs method then of $http request

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-http

I tried to use method then of $http because my code after this request is run before the request  result is return.So my parameters of response are undefined.

```
var reqgetcustomers = $http({
    url: 'api/customers/GetNbCustomer',
    params: {
        'lastName': lastName,
        'firstName': firstName,
        'address': address,
        'town': town,
        'zipCode': zipCode,
        'skip': -1,
        'take': -1
    }
};

reqgetcustomers.then(function (dataresult) {
    $scope.itemCount = dataresult.data;
    var nbPage = Math.ceil($scope.itemCount / $scope.numPerPage);
    locker.put('nbPage', nbPage);
    console.log('locker nbPage before=> ', locker.get('nbPage'));
    console.log('itemCount => ', $scope.itemCount);
});
```

I use the result of request after, but the nbPage variable is undefined.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I thinks nbPage  is undefined because you not defined this variable $scope.numPerPage.

Comment: I have only put  my request, so my var numPerPage is define outside of the request. The request run fine and it find my action in the api controller, but  my code continue without wait the request's result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded. This is my new code if it can help somebody:

```
    //create the promise
    function getCustomersRequest(lastName, firstName, address, town, zipCode, skip, take)
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var reqgetcustomers = $http({
            url: 'api/customers/GetNbCustomer',
            params: { 
                'lastName': lastName,
                'firstName': firstName, 
                'address': address,
                'town': town,
                'zipCode': zipCode,
                'skip': -1,
                'take': -1 
            } 
         });
         reqgetcustomers.success(function (dataResult) {
             deferred.resolve(dataResult);
         });
         return deferred.promise;
    }

    //new method with promise
    function GetListFiltered(lastName, firstName, address, town, zipCode, skip, take) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var reqSearchCustomers = $http({ 
            url: '/api/customers/GetFilteredList',
            params: { 
                'lastName': lastName,
                'firstName': firstName, 
                'address': address,
                'town': town, 
                'zipCode': zipCode,
                'skip': skip,
                'take': take 
            } 
        });
        reqSearchCustomers.success(function (dataResult) {
            deferred.resolve(dataResult);
            $scope.customers = dataResult;
        });
        var myPromise = getCustomersRequest(lastName, firstName, address, town, zipCode, skip, take);
        myPromise.then(function (resolve) {
            $scope.itemCount = resolve;
            locker.put('itemCount', resolve);
            locker.put('skip', ((locker.get('currentPage') - 1) * $scope.numPerPage));
            var nbPage = Math.ceil(locker.get('itemCount') / $scope.numPerPage);
            locker.put('nbPage', nbPage);
            $scope.skip = locker.get('skip');
            $scope.nbPage = locker.get('nbPage');
    }
    GetListFiltered(locker.get('lastName'), locker.get('firstName'), locker.get('address'), locker.get('town'), locker.get('zipCode'), $scope.skip, $scope.numPerPage);
```